# Script to convert fixed width flat file to csv

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to make a generic script which will convert a fixed width flat file into csv. Below is my approach:

```
`echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo a,b,c>final.txt

for /f "tokens=1 delims=;" %%i in (source.txt) do (
set x=%%i

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (config.txt) do (
call SET VAR=!x:~%%a,%%b!

for %%p in (!VAR!) do (echo/|set /p ="%%p,"
) >>final.txt

)

)
`
```

Config file which I am using contains the parameters for substring which states from where to do the substring and how many characters.

Config file contains:

```
0,9
9,3
12,11
23,7
30,1
31,1
32,5
37,9
46,9
55,3
58,9
67,9
76,9
85,9
94,1
```

Source file contains the actual fixed with source.

Now with my code I am getting the result but for the fields which has no value/empty in the source is not reflecting in the final output. 
Example:

Source:

```
1234<space>678 [col1=678,col2=space,col3=678]
```

Output (Current):

> 1234,678

Output(Expected):

> 1234,,678

Please help

Comment: Can you give a snippet of source.txt

Answer (score 0):

Your `for %%p in (!VAR!) do (…)` loop executes defined `(…)` command for all strings found in `!VAR!` delimited with white space(s). So if `!VAR!` results to all white spaces, then consequential `for %%p in (   ) do (…)` loop executes nothing. Next code snippet could help:

```
echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo a,b,c>final.txt
rem replace the €€€ string with any unused one
set "fooString=€€€" 
for /f "tokens=1 delims=;" %%i in (source.txt) do (
  set "x=%%i"
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (config.txt) do (
    call SET "VARraw=!x:~%%a,%%b!%fooString%"
    rem replaced with respect to the OP's comment: for %%p in (!VARraw!) do (
    for /F "tokens=*" %%p in ("!VARraw!") do (
      set "rav=%%p"
      set "var=!rav:%fooString%=!"
      echo/|set /p "=!var!,"
    ) >>final.txt
  )
)
```

**Edit**: note that `for /F "tokens=*" %%p in ("!VARraw!") do (` would remove leading spaces from the `!VARraw!` string.

Comment: I used your code but I seem to face one issue.Please find below how the output looks: <br/>
<br/>
<br/>

`Source:
S3340MAAAAAAAAA A A         77M12
<br/>
<br/>

Present Output:
S,334,0,M,AAAAAAAAA,A,A,,77,M,12
<br/>
<br/>

Expected Output:
S,334,0,M,AAAAAAAAAAA,77,M,12
`
<br/>
<br/>

As you can see it is considering the space between a field as a new field.